# How to prevent custom form from redirecting to google form submission response page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, google-forms

I have a custom HTML form that is connected to a google form. When the user submits the form the page redirects to forms.google.com "Your response has been recorded" page. How can I prevent the user from being redirected out of my site and instead give them a custom pop up saying the form was submitted. preventDefault and stopImmediatePropagation have not worked.

```
 <div>
    <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/...." target="_self" method="POST">
              <label class="formLabel" for="name">Name</label>
              <input class="inputValues" type="text" id="name" name="entry.1059844657" placeholder="Name"><br>
              <label class="formLabel" for="email">Email</label>
              <input class="inputValues" type="email" id="email" name="entry.2048065676" placeholder="abc@client.com"><br>
              <label class="formLabel" for="phone">Phone</label>
              <input class="inputValues" type="tel" id="phone" name="entry.1330942399" placeholder="111-222-3333"><br>
              <label class="formLabel" for="Email">Comments</label>
              <textarea class="inputValues" id="email" name="entry.2052823483" placeholder="Email"></textarea><br>
                 
              <button class="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

              </form>
```

```
document.querySelector(".submit").addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});


[![Google submission page][1]][1]
```